# CUDA: nvcc without CUDA toolkit

Tags: cuda

I need to compile an existing *.cu using the nvidia cuda compiler on different platforms. However, this would require to download and install VStudio as well as NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit for every platform. Is there a lightweight package, which only installs minimal required files for compiles *.cu sources?

Regards,
P

Comment: nvcc isn't a compiler, it is only a compiler driver, and it relies on a supported host compiler (cl, gcc or icc) to compile device code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the CUDA C Compiler Driver NVCC Reference Guide, Section 1.1.3:

> All non-CUDA compilation steps are forwarded to a general purpose C
>   compiler that is supported by nvcc, and on Windows platforms, where this compiler is
>   an instance of the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, nvcc will translate its options into
>   appropriate cl command syntax.

Quoting the same guide, Section 1.2

> `nvcc` uses the following compilers for host code compilation: On Windows platforms: The Microsoft Visual Studio compiler, `cl`.

You cannot disregard the use of Visual Studio for compiling CUDA programs on Windows platforms.